# Pagination in CakePHP using HABTM

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

Wow, CakePHP really hasn't got this problem sorted.

After hours of searching I came across the solution below (which may or may not be outdated), but I'm having issues applying paginatior 'limit' => 10 or other ordering.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

My model:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Post' => array(
        'className'              => 'Post',
        'joinTable'              => 'tags_posts',
        'foreignKey'             => 'tag_id',
        'associationForeignKey'  => 'post_id',  
        'order'                  => array('Post.created DESC'),
        'unique'                 => true
    )
);
```

In my controller in view()

```
public function view($id) {
    $this->Tag->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array('TagsPost')), false);     
    $this->set('tag', $this->paginate('Tag', array('TagsPost.tag_id' => $id))); 
}
```

In my view I then had to change:

```
foreach ($tag['Post'] as $post)
```

to

```
foreach ($tag[0]['Post'] as $post)
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to display in your view? All Posts with a certain tag? Also, I assume it is the View method of the Tags controller, that you are showing, right? Please be more specific. I might show you a good solution since I ran into the same or a similar problem recently.

Comment: We'll need to see your $this->paginate array. As you can set this before you paginate your records.

Answer (score 2):

Your view method should looks like:

```
public function view($id) {
      $this->Paginate['limit'] = 10;
      $this->Paginate['conditions'] = array('TagsPost.tag_id' => $id);
      $this->Tag->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array('TagsPost')), false);     
      $this->set('tag', $this->paginate('Tag')); 
}
```

Kindly ask if it not worked for you.

Comment: Good one. However, that is again binding other models.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with CakePHP 2.x

```
public function view ($id)
{
  $this->paginate = array (
                        'limit' => 10,
                        'conditions' => array('TagsPost.tag_id' => $id)
                    );
  $this->Tag->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array('TagsPost')), false);     
  $this->set('tag', $this->paginate('Tag')); 
}
```